Error about cv2.imshow when running code in google colab
I tried to run an image dehazing algorithm in Google Colab with the following complete code:
import cv2
import image_dehazer
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
# Install libraries
#!pip install image_dehazer opencv-python numpy scipy
​
def dehaze_image(image_path):
    # Read the image
    HazeImg = cv2.imread(image_path)
​
    # Dehaze the image
    HazeCorrectedImg, HazeMap = image_dehazer.remove_haze(HazeImg)
​
    # Show the original and dehazed images
    cv2_imshow(HazeImg)
    cv2_imshow(HazeCorrectedImg)
​
# Dehaze an image
dehaze_image('/content/Foggy Swamp Landscape.jpg')

However, regarding the line HazeCorrectedImg, HazeMap = image_dehazer.remove_haze(HazeImg), an error occurred as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DisabledFunctionError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-3033fa0dd766> in <cell line: 19>()
     17 
     18 # Dehaze an image
---> 19 dehaze_image('/content/Foggy Swamp Landscape.jpg')
​
4 frames 
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/colab/_import_hooks/_cv2.py in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     46   def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
     47     if not os.environ.get(env_var, False):
---> 48       raise DisabledFunctionError(message, name or func.__name__)
     49     return func(*args, **kwargs)
     50 
​
DisabledFunctionError: cv2.imshow() is disabled in Colab, because it causes Jupyter sessions to crash; see https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3935.
As a substitution, consider using
  from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

But I didn't use cv2.imshow, I used cv2_imshow instead.
I thought it might be because the wrong method was used in the image_dehazer library, so I copied the complete image_dehazer code content, in which cv2.imshow was used in one place. I changed it to cv2_imshow and successfully ran it. However, when I ran the original code again, it still reported an error in the same location.

A temporary solution, I noticed that in the image_dehazer library, the place where cv2.imshow is used is:
if (self.showHazeTransmissionMap):
            cv2_imshow("Haze Transmission Map", self._Transmission)
            cv2.waitKey(1)

That is, when showHazeTransmissionMap=True, it will enter this judgment block to display the image after dehazing. So I set showHazeTransmissionMap=False in
def remove_haze(HazeImg, airlightEstimation_windowSze=15, boundaryConstraint_windowSze=3, C0=20, C1=300, regularize_lambda=0.1, sigma=0.5, delta=0.85, showHazeTransmissionMap=True):

and then separately called cv2_imshow to display the image, and it ran successfully.
